# Add a drop down for records per page in grid.mvc

Tags: model-view-controller, paging, webgrid

I have a web grid (from grid.mvc) it has a by default paging property which is WithPaging(int value), i want it to provide a drop down for paging (by changing drop down the integer in WithPaging(int value) should be replaced by that drop down selected value).
[image]